# How to "crop" the MATLAB plot into a triangular one?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 2D scatter plot, wherein all the points are in fact guaranteed to fall into an equilateral triangle. So I wish to "crop" the region of interest, i.e., the triangle, out of the default square x-y system.

[image]

How may I do this? Even better if the method provided can be easily extended to a square, an equilateral pentagon, etc..

**P.S.**: The vertices of the equilateral triangle are `[[0 0.577350269189626];[0.500000000000000 -0.288675134594813];[-0.500000000000000   -0.288675134594813]]`.

Comment: Greying out the background, painting a white triangle and then scattering the points?

Comment: `T` your triangle points, `fill(T(:,1),T(:,2),'white','EdgeColor','none')` `set(gca,'color','none')` `hold on` and then `scatter`? By the way: If you export the figure you shouldn't see the grey background anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`inpolygon`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to detect which points are inside the polygon. This works for any polygon, not just triangles. You can then remove the axes and plot the polygon manually with [`patch`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) to produce the effect you want.

```
%// Define data:
x = rand(1,1000)-.5;
y = rand(1,1000)*.9-.3;
p = [0 0.577350269189626;
     0.500000000000000 -0.288675134594813;
     -0.500000000000000 -0.288675134594813];

%// Plot data before cropping
figure
plot(x,y,'o');

%// Select points inside the polygon:
ind = inpolygon(x,y,p(:,1),p(:,2));

%// Plot data after cropping
figure
plot(x(ind),y(ind),'o');

%// Plot cropped data with polygon and without axes:
figure
patch(p(:,1), p(:,2), 'w', 'edgecolor', 'r') %// polygon white background and red border
hold on
plot(x(ind),y(ind),'o'); %// plot points after polygon
axis off %// remove axes
```

Here are the three example figures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood me. I wish to have a plot that itself is a triangle. You can imagine we tilt y-axis until it collides with one triangular edge.

Comment: Cannot image it is that simple. THANK YOU

Comment: I didn't understand initially that you wanted that. I've edited my answer to include it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused. Even better, is it possible to make x and y-axis off and z-axis on (I have extended the thing to 3D)? On the internet is there no solution...

Comment: I don't think so. The `'Visible'` property (which is set to `'off'` when you do `axis off`) is common to all two/three axes

Comment: @rayryend The answer grew gradually as I slowly got to understand what the question was asking :-)